# upload multiple files with move_uploaded_file() function by using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload multiple files with for each loop. what should I use in the first parameter of move_uploaded_file() function in this case

```
            foreach ($_FILES["prodImg"]["name"] as $pImage) {
                $nbr++;
                $col = 'image' . $nbr;
                $fileName = basename($pImage);
                $target_file = $target_dir . "" . $fileName;
                $rqt = "UPDATE prodimages SET $col=? WHERE prodId= ? ";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($rqt);
                $stmt->execute(array($fileName, $pID));
                move_uploaded_file($pImage, $target_file);
            }
```

Comment: "what should I use in the first parameter of move_uploaded_file() function in this case "   RTM (Read The Manual) http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) you can use `$_FILES["prodImg"]["tmp_name"][$i]`:

```
foreach ($_FILES["prodImg"]["name"] as $i => $pImage) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["prodImg"]["tmp_name"][$i], /*..*/);
}
```

You can always `var_dump($_FILES);` to see what it looks like.

Comment: @AbdeAMNR if it works you need to mark it as correct answer and upvote it. don't mistake me.